# 4th Column of bootstrap col-md-4 position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am setting up a simple 3 column modular webpage that has content specific to each column. im using col-md-4 tags to give me the 3 column grid and in these columns each could be a different height. The first could be 400px high, the 2nd 400px high the 3rd 700px high. my problem is, when i add another column, i want it to be positioned directly underneath the 1st column (y=401px) not (y=701px).

i have read about the clearfix within bootstrap but this seems to actually create the issue im trying to resolve.

Comment: put each row in a row?

Comment: post your code or fiddle??

Comment: searching the internet for "bootstrap masonry" gave me this: http://www.bootply.com/1Tq35rlkbx (css only solution using css columns)